# Finding sense of work done

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, work

What will be the work done by a moment for small angular displacement "dtheta"  opposite to the direction of moment?
Is it positive or negative work done?

Comment: What is the definition of work? It is force times distance moved *in the direction of the force*.

Answer (score 0):

It will be dW < 0.

Work done by a force opposite to the direction of motion is negative. You'll see the force when you split the torque up into the force and the lever arm. The direction of motion through the distance ds is opposite to the force F, all by the right hand rule for defining positive orientation.